# How to remove objects from a list in order using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function, `throw_cards` that takes a Hand object, that has a certain number of Card objects in it, prints a message, and removes the card from the `self.cards` list.
This is what I currently have:

```
ability = {'Clubs':5, 'Diamonds':6, 'Hearts':7, 'Spades':8}

class Hand(Deck):
        """Represents a hand of playing cards."""
        def __init__(self, label=''): #name for hand? idk
            self.cards = []
            self.label = label

        def throw_cards(self):
            for card in self.cards:
                print(card, 'deals', ability[Card.suit_names[card.suit]],
                      'damage!')
                self.cards.remove(self.cards[0])
q = Hand()
w= Deck()
w.shuffle()
w.move_cards(q, 6)
```

Using the function this way I end up with

```
>>> q.throw_cards()
King of Hearts deals 7 damage!
5 of Clubs deals 5 damage!
10 of Hearts deals 7 damage!
>>> print(q)
3 of Diamonds
10 of Hearts
10 of Spades
```

The problem, it seems, is that it doesn't remove the cards in the right order. I have also tried using `.pop()` and different indices of `.remove()`, but can't get it to print and then remove the card from the Hand. Also, please let me know if this question itself is alright, in terms of formatting and information! I am very new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the list that you are iterating over, and this is causing the problem that you see.

Since you seem to want to remove all of the cards, why not just rebind `self.cards` to an empty list after you have finished printing them:

```
def throw_cards(self):
    for card in self.cards:
        print(card, 'deals', ability[Card.suit_names[card.suit]], 'damage!')
    self.cards = []
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This of course is hypothetical, but the reason that I would want the card to be deleted after the `print` is in case I would want to stop throwing the cards in the middle of the iteration (wrong word?). For example, if an enemy hit 0 HP after the third card thrown. Although, I know I would have to rewrite the method to have it behave like that.